# Clearing a default value in a search box with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can't seem to achieve this simple functionality! All I want is to clear a default search term in an input box when it is clicked. The following works up to a point but clears any *other* text entered, I would've thought resetting search_form_text should have solved this:

```
search_form_text = $('#block-search-0 #edit-search-block-form-l').attr('value');

if (search_form_text == 'Enter search keywords here') {

        $('#block-search-0 #edit-search-block-form-l').click(function() {           
            $('#block-search-0 #edit-search-block-form-l').attr('value', '');
            search_form_text = '';
        });

    }
```

Hmmmm... :)

Comment: Just one thing: You don't need to combine several IDs in a selector. As an ID is unique it is sufficient to do `$('#edit-search-block-form-l')`

Comment: This is not a dig at you, but I don't why people insist on using Jquery for everything, sure it makes selecting elements easier... but come on.

Comment: @thecoshman - Show me a shorter/cleaner way in vanilla javascript for this :)  I agree for some things it's overkill, but *most* things, it's cleaner, easier, and often faster.

Comment: @thecoshman: Maybe he already uses jQuery for something else. If so, why not use it :)

Comment: I would of had the code in the onfocus of the html (i know jquery likes to do-way with that method, but i prefer it) and just use "if(this.value != ''){ this.value = '' }" I would tend to do a similar thing for onblur "if(this.value == ''){this.value = 'Enter user name'}"

Comment: @thecoshman - It's still longer to do the same in javascript :) Here's this specific question both ways: http://jsfiddle.net/K6xxn/  Even if you stored it as a variable, 225+ bytes, still longer...and in jQuery I could change that selector and have it work on any number of elements, and *still* be shorter/easier.  Your choice of course, but I prefer jQuery simplifying things (and taking cross-browser out of the picture) in most cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try rearranging it like this:

```
$('#edit-search-block-form-l').click(function() {           
  if($(this).val() == 'Enter search keywords here') 
    $(this).val('');
});
```

This just prevents the user from searching for `'Enter search keywords here'` specifically, but is that really an issue?  Look up top on this page, type in "search", click out, then click the box again...would a user ever even notice it? probably not :)

The why it doesn't work part:
`$('#block-search-0 #edit-search-block-form-l').attr('value', '');` will clear the value every time, you need an if to see if you actually want to clear :)

Answer (score 5):

Why not do:

```
$('#edit-search-block-form-1').focus(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == "Enter search keywords here"){
   $(this).val("");
 }
});
$('#edit-search-block-form-1').blur(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == ""){
   $(this).val("Enter search keywords here");
 }
});
```

It will keep the description in the box, as long as the box is "blank".

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution here, seems cleaner to me: http://snipplr.com/view/15360/jquery-clear-default-input-values/

```
(function($){
$.fn.clearDefault = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var default_value = $(this).val();
        $(this).focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == default_value) $(this).val("");
        });
        $(this).blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "") $(this).val(default_value);
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);

// Usage: $('input.clear-default').clearDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If plain javascript is good for you..

```
document.getElementById('ElementId').value='';
```